# Wordpress: multiplas queries

Tags: php, wordpress

Eu estou fazendo queries para buscar posts de acordo com parâmetros diferentes de campos customizados, mas eu gostaria que no final o resultado das 3 queries fossem exibidos em conjunto.

```
function query() {
        foreach ($values1 as $value1) {
            $arrays[0][] = array(
                'key' => 'my-value1',
                'value' => $value1,
                'compare' => 'LIKE'
            );
        }

        $arrays[1]['relation'] = 'OR';
        foreach ($values2 as $value2) {
            $arrays[0][] = array(
                'key' => 'my-value2',
                'value' => $value2,
                'compare' => 'LIKE'
            );
        }

    if(!is_null($sofwares)) {
        $arrays[2]['relation'] = 'OR';
        foreach ($values3 as $value3) {
            $arrays[0][] = array(
                'key' => 'my-value3',
                'value' => $value3,
                'compare' => 'LIKE'
            );
        }
    }
}

$args = array(
'category' => 'my-category',
'posts_per_page'  => 5
);
$args['meta_query'] = query(); //chamo a função para montar
$posts = get_posts($args);
```

Como eu poderia fazer para que todos os resultados dessa query viessem todos juntos, como se fossem concatenados em um unico grupo de posts para ser mostrado no loop.
Tentei usar arrays para fazer multiplas queries, mas não está funcionando como esperado, que seria unir nos resultados todos os posts encontrados nas 3 queries.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Você pode usar a função: array_merge() para juntar os resultados encontrados, por exemplo:

```
        $args1 = array(
            'category' => 'my-category',
            'posts_per_page'  => 5
            'key' => 'my-value1',
            'value' => $value1,
            'compare' => 'LIKE'
        );
        $args2 = array(
            'category' => 'my-category',
            'posts_per_page'  => 5
            'key' => 'my-value2',
            'value' => $value2,
            'compare' => 'LIKE'
        );
        $posts_args1 = get_posts( $args1 );
        $posts_args2 = get_posts( $args2 );
        // todos os resultados será armazenada nessa variável, depois é so percorrer ;)  
        $mergedposts = array_merge( $posts_args1, $posts_args2 );
```

Comment: isso ajudou, obrigada

Comment: perfeito........